# product order summary using paypal sandbox is not showing in Firefox

Tags: php, mysql, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

I have set up a shopping website, with check out to Paypal.when you get to the payment summary page there are no products in the order and the balance is zero. 
in my pay.php i have the following code

```
<input type="text" name="item_name" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['productname']; ?>" />
<input type="text" id='amount' name="amount" value="<?php echo $_POST['final_amt']; ?>" class="des"/>
```

but I have tried the same code in Chrome and it works correctly.

Comment: try `<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['productname']; ?>" />`

Comment: i used type="hidden" also even though its not working.Thanks for your comment